# Laurent series $f(z)=\frac{z\sin(z)}{\cos(z)-1}$ and its singularity type?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

1. What was the singularity type of $\frac{z\sin(z)}{\cos(z)-1}$?
2. and what was its Laurent series expansion?

It was essential singularity. But I used $\displaystyle\frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2n+1}/(2n+1)!}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2n+1}/(2n+2)!}\approx\frac{\alpha z+\gamma_1(z)}{\beta z+\gamma_2(z)}$ where it seemed that the limit of $f(z)$ exists, which was wrong. how to prove it, and what was its laurent series expansionn?

Comment: $\cos(z)-1$ vanishes at $z=0,\pm 2\pi,\pm 4\pi,\cdots$ and its derivative $\sin(z)$ also vanishes at these points. The zeros of $\cos(z)-1$ are of order 2. So $0$ is a removable singularity of $f$. All other zeros of $\cos(z)-1$ result in first order poles of $f$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts but how to prove it formally? Both the numerator and denominator gots to 0 at singularities...

Comment: Expand $\cos(z)-1$ in a power series about $z=\pm 2n\pi$, and note that the function and its first derivative vanish at these points, but the second derivative does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $z=0$ we have

$$ \begin{align} 
\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z\sin z}{\cos z - 1} 
&= \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z\left(z - \frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)}{\left(1 - \frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^4}{4!} - \cdots \right) -1} \\
&= \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z^2 -
 \frac{z^4}{3!}+\cdots}{-\frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^4}{4!} - \cdots} \\
&= -2
\end{align} $$

making it a removable singularity

---

For $z = 2n\pi$

$$ \begin{align} \lim_{z\to 2n\pi} (z-2n\pi)\frac{z\sin z}{\cos z - 1} &= \lim_{w\to 0} \frac{w(w+2n\pi)\sin w}{\cos w - 1} \\
&= \lim_{w\to 0} \frac{w^2\sin w}{\cos w-1} + 2n\pi\lim_{w\to 0} \frac{w\sin w}{\cos w - 1} \\
&= 0 + 2n\pi(-2) \\
&= -4n\pi
\end{align} $$

making it a pole of order 1 for $n\ne 0$

---

Another way to see this is 
$$ \frac{z\sin z}{\cos z - 1} = -\frac{2z \sin \frac{z}{2} \cos \frac{z}{2}}{2\sin^2 \frac{z}{2}} = -z\cot \frac{z}{2} $$

which has simple poles at $\frac{z}{2} = n\pi$ except the origin

---

For the Laurent series (I'm assuming for $|z|<2\pi$), you will need to know the series for $\cot z$. Depending on the problem requirements, you can solve it term-by-term or look up a closed-form.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is beautiful.

Comment: why we can take limit inside in your first proof?

Comment: @MeetPatel Because the top and bottom power series have the same degree

Comment: which result exactly we are using there?

Comment: @MeetPatel Can you clarify your question? Not sure what you are asking